# How to wait for a console process to complete BEFORE running the other console process in wpf applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, process

I have 2 external process to run(2 console exe) that provide output to console. I am running these apps on wpf application. I capture console output and use it as input.

here how i do
1. run first process. capture the console output.
2. do some work using the first process output.
3. run the second process after i have the do some work output.

the problem i am having is i have to wait for the other process to finish and use its output before i can run the other process. By the time i want to run the second process, the first process havent been finished.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ExtProcess1();
    ExtProcess2();  //this is executed before ExtProcess1 OutputDataReceived is completely captured
    Instance = this;
}

public static void ExtProcess1()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}

static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainWindow.Instance.lbLog.Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        String s = (String)e.Data;
        MainWindow.Instance.lbLog.Items.Add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        MainWindow.Instance.lbLog.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
            new EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs>(corePingPid_OutputDataReceived), sender, new object[] { e });
    }
}
```

How do i force the wpf application to wait for the first process BEFORE running the second process?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Process class to execute and capture output for console, you can use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method. It will block the current thread till the process finish the execution. There is another overload that can block the current thread till the process finishes or specified timeout period elapsed.

Comment: This is what I use as well. Just be careful with it, because it will lock your GUI thread if you try to run it there.

Comment: i did use process.waitforexit(). i also use process.outputdatareceived, which is where i capture the console output.

Comment: @publicEnemy, where are you starting your second process? It should be on same thread after call to WaitForExit() for first process.

Comment: edited my questions. i cannot add code in comment which is my intention in my prev comments.

Comment: @publicENEMY, you should put call to process.BeginOutputReadLine() before process.WaitForExit().

Comment: @VinayC, did that. Still doesnt work. ExtProcess2 is executed before any output form ExtProcess1 is captured.

Comment: @publicENEMY, I believe that reason for this might be the fact that output data received handler is waiting on main thread to be free which happens when process2 gets finished (because it gets called immediately after process1). Can you try to read output synchronously - process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() followed by process.WaitForExit. I believe that it would be successful.

Comment: how do i do that. process.Start();
   process.BeginOutputReadLine();
   process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   process.WaitForExit(); having both beginoutputreadline and read to end will result in error stating cannot do sync and async simultaneously. removing beginoutput readline will never output anything. please help. thanks.

Comment: ok. now i understand how readtoend works. problem is, by adding waitforexit will block the current thread and make my ui unresponsive. can i read the standard output async and for the thread to wait until reading std output finished? thanks.

Comment: @publicENEMY, AFAIK, problem is that there is no clear way to find out if output has been finished. Only way that I could think that this will work is to then poll in UI thread (using timer) to see if process has exited (Process.HasExited). IMO, the better way would be to start new thread and execute both processes on that thread using synchronous output read - that way ur UI won't block.

Comment: if i use synchronous output read, can i dispay the results in realtime?

Comment: No - you can able to display it after process finishes it. If you want to display it as when o/p appears then you have to go asych way. But in such case, as suggested use a different thread to execute process, invoke BeginOutputReadLine() and then wait for exit.